# How can I add a notification to the notification bar based on a call from javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, notifications

How can I add a notification to the notification bar based on a call from javascript?

I have this:

```
package com.CheckInventory;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebStorage;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class CheckInventoryActivity extends Activity {
    WebView webview;
    String username; 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
        webView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myimage);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setDatabasePath("/data/data/"+this.getPackageName()+"/databases/");
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.124/android");
        webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

    }
    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/nodata.html");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not online", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()){
            //webview.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

JavascriptInterface.Java

```
package com.CheckInventory;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;

public class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

My Javascript is interfacing properly with the android app because I see the toast,  How do I add a Notification to the notification bar? I am very new to android, and do not know how to go from the examples that I have found on the internet to a useful state in my app.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: I'd start here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html, and incorporate that into the `showToast()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Also look at [Notifying the User](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/index.html). You should be able to replace your showToast with a notification. However, you should also look at the reference docs for JavaScriptInterface; Java objects need to be annotated with @JavascriptInterface.

Comment: Joe:   Thank you for the input, since I am very new to this, can you share some code that works?